# Is it possible to have initials show before image loads?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm using [Persona](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/persona) component and sometimes it takes time for the image to load.
Is it possible to show the user initials until the image loads? This exact behavior is in place in OWA.

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: @Tholle this isn't really about my code but about the library itself. Here's an example of Persona usage: https://codepen.io/dzearing/pen/XqVwrZ

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible using office-ui-fabric-react.
Opened a feature request:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/5601

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible via this PR https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/pull/5618

Use `showInitialsUntilImageLoads=true` to show initials until the image loads.